# ssh using powerShell script by passing the password along with the Commnad

Tags: powershell, ssh

im able to ssh into a server from PowerShell if i type

ssh username@host

This prompts a password and i enter the password which works

But im trying to write a script which ssh into a server executes some scripts and get back

so i have to pass the password along with the command how do i do this

there are lot of answers for shell script how do i do this in PowerShell

I have tried

echo "password" | ssh user@host

doesn't seem to work

Comment: just for your info:
in powershell  echo "password" outputs "password"
so you should use:
Write-Output "password" or echo password

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can work with [POSH-SSH module](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH).

Code snippet:

```
$Password = "Password"
$User = "UserName"
$ComputerName = "Destination"
$Command = "SSH Command"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials #Connect Over SSH

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $SessionID.Sessionid -Command $Command # Invoke Command Over SSH
```

UPDATE:

3 years later, Microsoft publishes `PowerShell remoting over SSH`.

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Dude Thanks a lot,  I've been trying to do this all day, Im new and so i cant upVote your answer But it works Thanks a lot