# How do I run cygwin ssh properly on powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssh, cygwin, sshpass

My OS is Windows 10 (x64) and I installed both Powershell 7 and cygwin.

Then, I installed "sshpass" using cygwin.

And, here are the cases I am experiencing right now.

1. From cmd, if I enter "C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -", cygwin pops up with initial directory "~". Then, if I type "sshpass -p<password> ssh <username>@<host>", it perfectly works smoothly!
2. From cmd, if I enter "C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe", cygwin pops up with directory "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname". Then, if I type "sshpass -p<password> ssh <username>@<host>", it asks me to type the password. This means that sshpass is not working correctly here.
3. From powershell, if I type "C:\cygwin64\bin\sshpass.exe -p<password> C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh <username>@<host>", nothing happens.

My questions are the following:

1. How do I properly run sshpass command in Powershell?
2. Let's say my ip address is 1.1.1.1 and I am connecting to a server whose ip is 2.2.2.2, and both computers OS systems are Windows. When I connect to the server through ssh, it shows the "cmd" terminal of the server. How can I change it to show "cygwin" terminal when I connect to the server?

I am having very hard time fixing this out.. Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: PLEASE wrap you code in code formatting. the how-to for that is linked in the Tour page for this site AND in the page you used to create your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i am getting this, anyway, if i understand correctly you have a hard time launching sshpass from powershell.

Try using Start-Process commandlet: (maybe add the full path to ssh in arguments (?))

```
start-process -filepath C:\cygwin64\bin\sshpass.exe -ArgumentList '-p<password> ssh <username>@<host>' -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Anyway instead of reaching linux commands to windows and run it from powershell, why don't you check powershell modules?

[ssh using powerShell script by passing the password along with the Commnad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923868/ssh-using-powershell-script-by-passing-the-password-along-with-the-commnad)

Also, Powershell Remoting towards linux is a thing nowadays, and it runs over ssh (not bash afaik)

Comment: I also checked the post in the link you provided.. However, I do not understand how to use that script given in the post with Posh-SSH. I installed Posh-SSH and then what to do..? Could you please tell me how to use that script?